# Can I customize the svnadmin create process?

Tags: linux, svn

I have many different repositories setup on my server. I need to have an identical post-commit hook file in every one of those repos. Simple enough for existing, but is there a way to have calls to **svnadmin create** automatically copy a post-commit stub file to the new hooks directory? Essentially I'm looking for a *post-svnadmin-create* hook. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to wrap the call to svnadmin create in a script that creates the hooks after the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed as long as there is not some built-in way, which there seems not to be. I would have expected subversion to sport something like the customizable skeleton directory for new Linux users. Too bad.

Here is my wrapper with comments if anyone can find it useful - should be fairly extendable. If anyone notices any glaring gotchas in it, don't hesitate - I'm neither a bash nor Linux expert but I think I got most of it covered, and it works :)

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# A wrapper for svnadmin to allow post operations following repo creation - copying custom
# hook files into repo in this case. This should be run as root. 

# capture input args; note that args[0] == $@[1] (this script name is not captured here)
args=("$@");

# redirect args to svnadmin in all cases - this script should not modify the behavior of svnadmin.
# note: the original binary "/binary_path/svnadmin" has been renamed "/binary_path/svnadmin-wrapped" and 
# this script was then named "/binary_path/svnadmin" and given identical user:group & permissions as
# the original.
sudo -u svnuser svnadmin-wrapped ${args[@]};

# capture return code so we can return on exit; svnadmin returns 0 for success
eCode=$?;

# find out if sub-command to svnadmin was "create" and, if so, note the index of the directory arg,
# which is not necessarily going to be in the same position each time (options may be specified 
# before the sub-command).
path_idx=0;
found=0;
for i in ${args[@]}
do
    # track index; pre-incerement
    ((path_idx++));
    if [ $i == "create" ]
        then
        # found repo path
        ((found++));
        break;
    fi
done

# we now know if the subcommand was create and where the repo path is - finish up as needed.
# note that this block assumes that our hook file stubs are /stub_path/ (owned by root) 
# and that there exists a custom log file at /stub_path/cust-log (also owned by root).
d=`date`;
if [ $found != 0 ]
    then
    # check that the command succeeded 
    if [ $eCode == 0 ]
        then
        # check that the directory exists
        if [ -d "${args[$path_idx]}/hooks" ]
            then
            # copy our custom hooks into place
            sudo -u svnuser cp "/stub_path/post-commit" "${args[$path_idx]}/hooks/post-commit";
            sudo -u svnuser cp "/stub_path/post-revprop-change" "${args[$path_idx]}/hooks/post-revprop-change";
        else
            # unlikey failure; set custom error code here; log issue
            echo "$d svnadmin wrapper error: svnadmin 'create' succeeded but the 'hooks' directory was not found! Params: ${args[@]}" >> "/stub_path/cust-log";
            let "eCode=1325";
        fi
    else
        # tried to create but svnadmin failed; log issue
        echo "$d svnadmin wrapper error: svnadmin 'create' was called but failed! Params: ${args[@]}" >> "/stub_path/cust-log";
    fi
fi
exit $eCode;
```

-Thanks to all who host and post!